# Gson string with key

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, gson

I am using Gson to get convert the object to json string, and its working fine but when I am sending that json to a webservice method using post, I have to add the post method's parameter name in the string.

Example:

jsonString I get from Gson `new Gson().toJson(requestDataDTO)` :

```
{
  "req": {
    "AppId": "2",
    "ThirdParty": "3",
    "UserId": "1",
    "UserToken": "4"
  },
  "req1": {
    "AppId": "-33",
    "ThirdParty": "3",
    "UserId": "1",
    "UserToken": "4"
  }
}
```

jsonString I want :

```
{
  "requestDataDTO": {
    "req": {
      "AppId": "2",
      "ThirdParty": "3",
      "UserId": "1",
      "UserToken": "4"
    },
    "req1": {
      "AppId": "-33",
      "ThirdParty": "3",
      "UserId": "1",
      "UserToken": "4"
    }
  }
}
```

for now I am adding this `"requestDataDTO"` string at the start of json string I got from Gson.

is there a way to achieve this ?

Comment: Hi Rohit. Do you need some more information? :)

Comment: No.. Your previous answer helped me. Let me accept that. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an object which looks somehow like this:

```
package com.dominikangerer.q25077756;

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class RequestDataDTO {
    // {"AppId":"2","ThirdParty":"3","UserId":"1","UserToken":"4"}

    @SerializedName("AppId")
    private String appId;
    @SerializedName("ThirdParty")
    private String thirdParty;
    @SerializedName("UserId")
    private String userId;
    @SerializedName("UserToken")
    private String userToken;

    public String getAppId() {
        return appId;
    }

    public void setAppId(String appId) {
        this.appId = appId;
    }

    public String getThirdParty() {
        return thirdParty;
    }

    public void setThirdParty(String thirdParty) {
        this.thirdParty = thirdParty;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserToken() {
        return userToken;
    }

    public void setUserToken(String userToken) {
        this.userToken = userToken;
    }

}
```

The easiest and also for me most readable solution would be to create an wrapper/container Class which contains a HashMap (key/value) like this:

```
package com.dominikangerer.q25077756;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class RequestDataDTOContainer {

    private HashMap<String, RequestDataDTO> requestDataDTO = new HashMap<String, RequestDataDTO>();

    public HashMap<String, RequestDataDTO> getRequestDataDTO() {
        return requestDataDTO;
    }

    public void setRequestDataDTO(HashMap<String, RequestDataDTO> requestDataDTO) {
        this.requestDataDTO = requestDataDTO;
    }

    public void putRequestDataDTO(String key, RequestDataDTO value){
        this.requestDataDTO.put(key, value);
    }

}
```

To run it simply test it with a main like this:

```
// enable pretty printing
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

// too lazy to fill the objects by hand
String reqJson = "{\"AppId\":\"2\",\"ThirdParty\":\"3\",\"UserId\":\"1\",\"UserToken\":\"4\"}";
String req1Json = "{\"AppId\":\"-33\",\"ThirdParty\":\"3\",\"UserId\":\"1\",\"UserToken\":\"4\"}";

// deserialize it with gson
RequestDataDTO req = gson.fromJson(reqJson, RequestDataDTO.class);
RequestDataDTO req1 = gson.fromJson(req1Json, RequestDataDTO.class);

// initiliaze the container
RequestDataDTOContainer container = new RequestDataDTOContainer();

// adding the 2 req objects with the certain key
container.putRequestDataDTO("req", req);
container.putRequestDataDTO("req1", req1);

// Print it as pretty json
System.out.println(gson.toJson(container));
```

You are now more flexibility if you want to add more meta information like a whole meta object or similar without adding a hardcoded String to that json.

You can find the whole Example in this github repository: [Java Stackoverflow Answers by DominikAngerer](https://github.com/DominikAngerer/StackoverflowJavaAnswers/tree/6c40d9b57012bd5cff811cf3af511437aef66774/src/main/java/com/dominikangerer/q25077756)